# 倒立振子のモーターのギヤ比

Tags: ハードウェア

倒立振子を作っているのですが、パラメタを4日もチューニングしているのに立ちません。トルクは足りているはずですが転びます。もしかすると、ギヤの減速比が大き過ぎて遅れが生じているのかなと思いました。
pololu 172:1　メタルギアドモーター　です。ギヤ比は関係ありますでしょうか？

Comment: 同メーカー？らしいキットは30/50/75:1が推奨のようです。[Pololu Balboa 32U4 倒立振子ロボットキット](https://www.physical-computing.jp/product/1678) 多くの人に参考にされているらしい記事では114.7:1ですね。[半日で作る倒立振子](https://www.instructables.com/%E5%8D%8A%E6%97%A5%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B%E5%80%92%E7%AB%8B%E6%8C%AF%E5%AD%90/) ただそれだと遅めという記事も。[PIC マイコンとジャイロセンサを使った倒立振子](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~kano/pdf/course/SP4.pdf) 他に203.7:1は遅すぎという記事。[倒立振子制作日記（そのいち）](http://13mzawa2.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/09/04/203423)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ギヤの減速比が小さいと、力が不足してモータで振り子を動かせないように、振り子を固定できないようになりますよ。